# Vim: Why is the first non-space being added to my register?

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have a line that looks like this:

```
    foo1/bar1/baz1
```

That is 4 spaces in front.  I typed this in normal mode:

```
0vllll"ay
```

If I look in my `:reg` it says:

```
"a       f
```

Why is that `f` in there?  It wasn't highlighted.  Here's a screenshot showing that:

[image]

I expected the register to look like this:

```
"a
```

That's just 4 spaces.

I'm using cygwin's Vim.

Comment: Your cursor is on the `f`. (Although you can't see it due to the color of the cursor for some reason). So it is in the visual region. When you are on the first character of the line moving right 4 times puts the cursor on the `f`.

Comment: @FDinoff ah, thanks.  Any idea how to fix this visually?

Comment: Use `viw` to select all that whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has two different selection modes: *inclusive* (the default) and *exclusive*. With the former, the character the cursor is on is included in the visual selection. After your `04l`, the cursor rests on the `f`, and that's why it is included. You can either adapt the motion (`3l`), skip the intermediate visual mode and choose an exclusive one (e.g. `0"ayw`, or the `iw` text object), or change the selection mode via

```
:set selection=exclusive
```